# Using one query's result into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query which shows the below result, I want to use this MarksObtained and take out min, max and avg of each course and show it with the second query (have provided below).

```
select 
    CourseName, StdID, MarksObtained 
from 
    stdmarks
inner join 
    course on course.courseid = stdmarks.examid

+--------------------------+-------+---------------+
|        CourseName        | StdID | MarksObtained |
+--------------------------+-------+---------------+
| Digital Logic            |     1 |            20 |
| Visual Prog              |     1 |            20 |
| Computer Arch and Design |     1 |            20 |
| Digital Logic            |     2 |            20 |
| Visual Prog              |     2 |            20 |
+--------------------------+-------+---------------+
```

This is the second query

```
select 
    distinct CourseName, TeacherName, SemName 
from 
    teacher
inner join 
    stdcourseteacher on teacher.teacherid = stdcourseteacher.teacherid
inner join 
    course on course.courseid = stdcourseteacher.courseid
inner join 
    semester on stdcourseteacher.semid = semester.semid

+-------------------------+-------------+----------+
|       CourseName        | TeacherName | SemName  |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+
| Business Communications | Dr. Iman    | Fall2021 |
| Calculus - 1            | Dr. Khalid  | Fall2021 |
| Calculus - 2            | Dr. Khalid  | Fall2020 |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

So it will basically show min, max and avg of each course achieved by the students.

What I want:

```
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+-----+
|       CourseName        | TeacherName | SemName  | Min | Max | Avg |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| Business Communications | Dr. Iman    | Fall2021 |  80 |  20 |  50 |
| Calculus - 1            | Dr. Khalid  | Fall2021 |  70 |  15 |  45 |
| Calculus - 2            | Dr. Khalid  | Fall2020 |  85 |  15 |  50 |
+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Sample data:

StdMarks table:

```
+-------+--------+---------------+
| StdID | ExamID | MarksObtained |
+-------+--------+---------------+
|     1 |      9 |            20 |
|     1 |     10 |            20 |
|     1 |     11 |            20 |
+-------+--------+---------------+
```

StdCourseTeacher Table:

```
+-------+----------+------------+-------+
| StdID | CourseID | TeacherID  | SemID |
+-------+----------+------------+-------+
|     1 |        9 |          7 |     6 |
|     1 |       10 |          7 |     6 |
|     1 |       11 |          2 |     6 |
|     2 |        9 |          7 |     6 |
|     2 |       10 |          7 |     6 |
+-------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Exam Table:

```
+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
| ExamID | EvalID |  Topic   | MaxMarks | SemID | CourseID | TeacherID |
+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
|      1 |      3 | Mid-Term |       20 |     6 |        1 |         3 |
|      2 |      3 | Mid-Term |       20 |     6 |        2 |         4 |
|      3 |      3 | Mid-Term |       20 |     6 |        3 |         7 |
+--------+--------+----------+----------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Course Table:

```
+----------+---------------------------+----------+
| CourseID |        CourseName         | Semester |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+
|        1 | Calculus - 1              |        1 |
|        2 | Business Communications   |        1 |
|        3 | Introduction To Computing |        1 |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+
```

Semester Table:

```
+-------+------------+
| SemID |  SemName   |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | Spring2020 |
|     2 | Summer2020 |
+-------+------------+
```

Teacher Table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| TeacherID | TeacherName |
+-----------+-------------+
|         2 | Dr. Ahmed   |
|         3 | Dr. Khalid  |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: You need to show sample data and desired results. None of your data above includes min, max avg.

Comment: If you were to add your sample data as DDL+DML it makes it much easier for us to assist.

Comment: I have updated it with sample data, I wanna use functions MIN, MAX and AVG on the MarksObtained column I have achieved in the first query I have written above. But I wanna merge that query with the second one so that it will show MIN, MAX and AVG of each course. Basically if Student ID 1 has 10 marks in Calculus and Student ID 2 has 20 marks in Calculus, so it will show Max 20, Min 10, Avg 15 in front of Calculus.

Comment: Can I have a link to see how DDL+DML sample would look like

Comment: Its the create table, insert into table statements which create and populate some tables for testing.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70056036/group-by-with-respect-to-2-columns-and-get-min-max-and-avg-from-them

Comment: I thought I deleted it. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `group by` in order to use aggregate functions as follows:

```
select CourseName, TeacherName, SemName, min(MarksObtained), Max(MarksObtained), avg(MarksObtained)
from teacher T
inner join CT on CT.teacherid = T.teacherid
inner join course C on C.courseid = CT.courseid
inner join semester S on S.semid = CT.semid
inner join stdmarks M on M.examid = C.courseid
group by CourseName, TeacherName, SemName
```

Comment: It has given me the result but just not sure if it's accurate because it's all just "20" will have to verify. Thank you

Comment: Yeah you would normally create test data which does verify that any calculations are working.

Comment: hey, it actually worked. Thank you.